# How should I design my schema in Firebase when saving Google Locations?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

Here's what I'm trying to do:
I want to post a location into the database and then let someone to find those areas if he's nearby the location by perhaps 200m or less.

Firebase is using NoSQL, so how do I find those locations if I was the other guy?

Example:

1) I post a location `My house` with the values of latitude & longitude `-127.0090` & `37.78825`.

2) We have a user nearby `My house` but how does he/she locate `My house` with his latitude & longitude?

I'm not sure if you could understand, but I'm basically clueless on the schema design.

Comment: You're looking for GeoFire, which is a library that allows GeoQueries on the Firebase Database. See https://github.com/firebase/geofire

Comment: can you add this as an answer? Thanks

Comment: Good to hear that my comment helped Joshua. In this case I'm going to vote to close your question. If I post the comment as an answer it would (correctly) be closed as a link-only-answer and I have little interest in writing the basics of GeoFire up in the answer. I'm pretty sure there is an existing question and answer that covers your case, but I couldn't' find it with a quick search.